# Core data multithreading with children contexts

Tags: ios, iphone, multithreading, core-data

I have just began learning Core data. When it comes to multithreading, some blogs say that in this case we should use children contexts (by creating a context and setting its parent) and just invoke the performBlock: method. However some other blogs say that we should avoid this approach since it has introduced many bugs.
I have just began developing an application that manipulates a large data base and the project manager voted for Core data (instead of SQLLite).
Could any one please give me some directions. Should i use the children contexts strategy (introduced since iOS 5) or is there a better way to perform multithreading with Core Data ?
Thanks.

Comment: this guide from apple should cover the correct method. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html

Comment: thanks for your answer. But i have gone through the whole document and does not give an idea about the best strategy. All i want to know is : should i use nested contexts or not ?

Comment: if you  check this link http://wbyoung.tumblr.com/post/27851725562/core-data-growing-pains you will find that it is discouraging us from using this new technique (nested contexts). However in this link http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/ we are told and advised to use it. I am confused.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should i use the children contexts strategy (introduced since iOS 5)
>   or is there a better way to perform multithreading with Core Data ?

In addition to the concept you mentioned, Managed Object Contexts have built-in concurrency support without parent contexts (see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-CoreData/index.html).

If you create one using `initWithConcurrencyType:`, you can use `performBlock:` and `performBlockAndWait:` and the threading will be handled for you, assuming you follow the basic patterns outlined in the link above.  The parent/child context approach can help you with synchronization.

There's also an NSOperation-based approach outlined here: http://www.objc.io/issue-2/common-background-practices.html.  I personally wouldn't use it, because the built-in APIs are sufficient, but the article is very well written and should give you a good idea of what's going on.

How you implement this depends on the needs of your app.

> some other blogs say that we should avoid this approach since it has
>   introduced many bugs.

I would ignore them, and focus on writing clean code for yourself.  There are plenty of apps that use multithreading + Core Data without bugs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also do not want to use multithreading based on NSOperation.So as far as i have understood from your answer, there is no harm in using the nested contexts technique.

Comment: That's correct.  The main technique to avoid bugs is to make sure you understand concurrency programming generally - how queues and threads interact, etc.  If you're new at that, read the Concurrency Programming Guide (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).  If you know that stuff pretty well, I would just dive in and get started.

Comment: Well i am not new to Concurrency programming since i am a big fan of the GCD. Well, i am taking your advice in consideration and i am using the nested contexts technique since my data base contains up to 30 000 rows and may be more (for a single table). And that makes fetching and saving operations very slow and UI blocking. Thanks for the great answer. I accept and tick.